# Find general solution for $\tan{x} +\tan{2x} +\tan{3x}= 0$

Tags: trigonometry

My approach :-

$\tan{(x+2x)}= \tan{3x}$

$\tan{x}+\tan{2x} = \tan{3x}(1-\tan{x}.\tan{2x})$

Putting this in my equation ,

$\tan{3x}.(2-\tan{x}tan{2x}) =0$

Now either

$\tan{3x}= 0$    or  $\tan{x}\tan{2x}=2$

Hence we get either

$x=\frac{n\pi}{3}$    or  $x= n\pi ± \arctan{\frac{1}{√2}}.$

However , my textbook says that the solution is

$x=n\pi$    or    $x= n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$

Why is there a disparity in both the solutions? If they are equivalent , how?

I apologize in advance as I'm using latex for the first time. Thank You

Comment: Please typeset in *MathJax*.  Put dollar signs around equations, as I did on your first line.

Comment: Thank you I'll fix it quickly

Comment: And in the title as well....  Also, plain text should be {\rm here\ are\ words}, if between dollar signs.  (This stands for "Roman" font... not italic math font.)

Comment: your mistake is believe the book is correct ;-p just make a plot and you will notice your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan x+\tan2x=\dfrac{\sin(x+2x)}{\cos x\cos2x}$$

$$\implies\sin3x(\cos3x+\cos x\cos2x)=0$$ with $\cos x\cos2x\cos3x\ne0$

What if $\sin3x=0?$

Else $$-\cos3x=\cos x\cos2x$$

Now $\cos3x=\cos x(4\cos^2x-3)=\cos x(2(1+\cos2x)-3)$

As $\cos x\ne0,$

$$\cos2x=-(2\cos2x-1)$$

Can you take it from here to reach at your second solution

Comment: Sir how do you type so many coding in second?I am using a mobile phone ,and it takes time to answer.any suggestions to how I can answer quickly?

Comment: Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution

Comment: @Nimu, it's all practice, no magic. I've learnt a small subset of latex that too from here only

Comment: Okk I understand. Thank you dada.

Comment: Yes , I get it. Thank You. But where is my method going wrong? If not, are the two solutions equivalent?

Comment: @ijustwannacry, Your solution is clearly a superset of that of the textbook

Comment: Thank You that was my actual query haha :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't follow your approach, so I'll show my own. You'll want to double-check all the calculations.

Define $t:=\tan x$ so $\tan 2x=\frac{2t}{1-t^2},\,\tan 3x=\frac{t(3-t^2)}{1-3t^2}$ and $\tan x+\tan 2x+\tan 3x=\frac{2t(3-t^2)(1-2t^2)}{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\left(1-3t^{2}\right)}$. This is $0$ iff $t\in\left\{0,\,\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\,\pm\sqrt{3}\right\}$.

Comment: Sorry I have a bad habit of skipping a couple of steps in between :(

Answer (score 0):

Remember
$$\tan (2 x)=\frac{2 \tan (x)}{1-\tan ^2(x)}$$
and
$$\tan(3x)=\frac{\tan (x) \left(\tan ^2(x)-3\right)}{3 \tan ^2(x)-1}$$
So the given equation can be written as
$$\frac{2 \tan (x)}{1-\tan ^2(x)}+\frac{\left(\tan ^2(x)-3\right) \tan (x)}{3 \tan ^2(x)-1}+\tan (x)=0$$
Adding the fractions
$$\frac{2 \tan (x) \left(\tan ^2(x)-3\right) \left(2 \tan ^2(x)-1\right)}{\left(\tan ^2(x)-1\right) \left(3 \tan ^2(x)-1\right)}=0$$
which is verified when
$$\tan(x)=0\lor \tan ^2(x)-3=0\lor 2 \tan ^2(x)-1=0$$
that is, $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$x=k\pi\lor x=\pm \frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi \lor x=\pm\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\right)+k\pi$$

Comment: What my problem is that , why is my solution set and one in the textbook different? Are they equivalent? If so , how?

Comment: @ijustwannacry Your book is wrong see here https://imgur.com/6Q2ZqLR

Comment: Yes I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\tan x$ and $T=\tan2x$. Then

$$\tan x+\tan2x+\tan3x=t+T+{T+t\over1-Tt}=(T+t)\left({2-Tt\over1-Tt} \right)$$

So $\tan x+\tan2x+\tan3x=0$ if and only if $T+t=0$ or $2-Tt=0$. Using $T=2t/(1-t^2)$, these become (after a little algebra)

$$t(3-t^2)=0\quad\text{or}\quad1-2t^2=0$$

from which we have $\tan x=0$, $\pm\sqrt3$, or $\pm1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: My query lies more in finding the reasoning why there is a disparity in both the solutions.

Comment: @ijustwannacry, sorry, I thought that was taken care of in achille hui's comment. Even the best of books occasionally make mistakes.

Comment: Yeah my bad , I forgot to accept an answer.

Comment: @ijustwannacry, no problem. The fun here was trying to streamline the solution.